# Can I use IN operator to query data in case sensitive manner in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

The following:

```
select * from people where first_name in ('John', 'Jim');
```

will bring all people that have first_name like

- John
- john
- jIm
- JIM

and all sorts of such combinations because the query is run in case insensitive mode.

How can I make this run in case sensitive mode?

I tried:

```
select * from people where first_name in binary ('John', 'Jim');
```

but it does not work.

Please, do not tell me to change the collation of the column. I want to have this dynamically, depending on user's choice (to query case sensitively or case insensitively).

Anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with `binary` is good, but you to apply it to the column name instead of the search terms. This way, the index will not be used. However, you can use a combination:

```
WHERE first_name in ('John','Jim') AND BINARY first_name in ('John','Jim')
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
select * from people 
where first_name COLLATE latin1_general_cs in ('John', 'Jim');
```